# I splitted my project into .h and .c files. Is it the proper way I should do this?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I've got a C program (shop database based on linked list, every shop has a sub linked-list of products).

I've got 4 .c files:

```
-> interface.c //functions for interface | #include interface.h
-> products.c // funcs for managing product list | #include products.h
-> shop.c // funcs for managing shop list | #include shop.h
-> main.c // int main(); only | #include main.h
```

I've got 4 .h files:

```
-> interface.h // prototypes from interface.c | #include main.h
-> products.h // prototypes from products.c | #include main.h
-. shop.h // prototypes from shop.c | #include main.h
-> main.h (I put there my global constants from #define, enum and structs from shop linked list and product sub linked list and standard libraries like stdio etc.)
```

btw. projects works, but in main.c() Visual Studio underlines every function.
Is this the proper way I split my project into .c and .h files?

Comment: Each of your header files should be the first include in each of your .c files ... this will test them for consistency and make sure that all of your (non-static) functions are defined before using them.

Comment: @JumBalter, ok, now is it proper to add main.h to every .c file? otherwise it's not working :/

Comment: Sure it's proper, but it's already included by being included into the other header files. Presumably you're using include guards. If something isn't working, you need to be more explicit about what is going wrong.

Comment: @JimBalter, yeah, I'm aware of this..., but when I'm not adding main.h to every .c file, there is no no access to the structures, standard libraries etc. I think it might be the reason it's not working. 
On the other hand I know, it should work, since #include just replaces #include with whole file contet and I added all .h libraries to main.c as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can split that project that way but in main.c file you need to include every header file that's why VS is showing line.

Comment: ok, now is it proper to add main.h to every .c file?
otherwise it's not working

Comment: It's only necessary include header files for the features being used.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some nice slides about [organizing C programs](http://www.cse.shirazu.ac.ir/~azimi/prog88/lectures/15large_programs.pdf).

As for the headers and how to use and manage them, you can read [these guidelines](http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/CHeaderFileGuidelines.pdf).

Visual Studio underlines your functions probably because you don't have the proper include paths set in your IDE, or you haven't `#include`d all the necessary headers.

Answer (score 1):

You also must close your code of .h file within the following types..

```
#ifndef _HEADERFILE_NAME_H_
#define _HEADERFILE_NAME_H_
..... <your code will be here>
#endif
```

Comment: Recommend to drop the leading _ , even though a leading _ is a widespread practice.  C reserves various identifiers for future use including all that begin with an _ + 'Uppercase'.  Details are in C11 7.1.3.